# Completion of an extension $K|\mathbb{Q}$ w.r.t. a non archimedean abs. value, isomorphic to $K\cdot \mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory

As the title suggests I want to prove the following result:

> given $\mathfrak{p}|(p)$, prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ over $p$, we have the canonical absolute value induced by it on $K$, and we can complete $K$ and obtain $K_{\mathfrak{p}}| \mathbb{Q}_p$ a new field extension. I want to prove that $K_{\mathfrak{p}}\cong \mathbb{Q}_p\cdot K$.

the inclusion $\mathbb{Q}_p\cdot K \subseteq K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is clear. But I don't know how to show the other. I know by Krasner's lemma that I can assume $K_{\mathfrak{p}}=\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha)$, for $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}^{alg}$ (algebraic closure), but I don't know how to prove that $\alpha \in K$.

Comment: Exactly how do you define $K\cdot\Bbb Q_p$? I presume you’re speaking of a compositum of two fields, and to define this, you’ll need them both to dwell inside some bigger field.

Comment: @Lubin yes you'r right. I'm a little bit sloppy here, but surely I fixed a bigger field and claim that $K\cdot \mathbb{Q}_p$ is the smallest field containing both.

Comment: Actually, this is the very nub of the problem. I’ll explain in an answer when I get time.

Comment: yes, I'm starting see the point you are making! thanks for stressing this detail, I'll wait for your answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To form a compositum $K\Bbb Q_p$, the two fields must be injected in some way into a larger field. You want something like an algebraic closure $\Omega$ of $\Bbb Q_p$, and then try to map $K$ into it. But there will be $[K:\Bbb Q]$ such embeddings into $\Omega$. Which one?

Let’s take a specific example, $K=\Bbb Q[a]/(a^3-10)$, what you get by adjoining a cube root of $10$ to $\Bbb Q$. If your $p$ is $3$, then $K$ has three embeddings into an algebraic closure $\Omega$ of $\Bbb Q_3$. As it happens, $\Bbb Q_3$ already has a cube root of $10$, call it $b$, and $a\mapsto b$ gives one embedding of $K$ into $\Bbb Q_3$. But in $\Bbb Q_3(\omega)$ ($\omega$ a primitive cube root of unity), there are two more cube roots of $10$, so there are two embeddings of $K$ into that extension of $\Bbb Q_3$. One way to look at this is to take the minimal $\Bbb Q$-polynomial for $a$, namely $X^3-10$, and look it as a $\Bbb Q_3$-polynomial, in which case it factors as $(X-b)(X^2+bX+b^2)$, linear times irreducible quadratic. Each factor gives you an equivalence class of embeddings of $K$ into $\Omega$.

But which embedding is the right one? You’ve framed the question in terms of a prime over $p$; in this case, $(3)=\mathfrak p_1\mathfrak p_2^2$, both primes being of degree one. If you complete with respect to $\mathfrak p_1$, the completion is (isomorphic to) $\Bbb Q_3$; if $\mathfrak p_2$, the completion is $\Bbb Q_3(\omega)$.

With all this, I think you can see your way to your desired conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try to show directly that $\mathbb Q_p \cdot K$ is complete.